# how to get my code to error display when it reads a string or letter

Tags: c++

when i read from text file, my code stops if it encounter a string or letter instead of display "Y" as the error,how should i fix that ? thank you for you help

text file example:
0 
5 
-5
y7
4 
u
5
10

```
if (file.is_open())
{
    int num = 0;
    while (file >> num)//reading from text file     
    {
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 15)
        {
            b = a + num;//changing the frist 4 ports only and last 4 port stays the same
            WritePortB(b);
            cout << Binary(b) << endl;;//prints our binary numbers
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Y" << endl;// ERROR CHECK 3 : VALID NUMBER RANGE
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file.is_open())
{
    int num = 0;
    while (file >> num)//reading from text file     
    {
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 15)
        {
            b = a + num;//changing the frist 4 ports only and last 4 port stays the same
            WritePortB(b);
            cout << Binary(b) << endl;;//prints our binary numbers
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    cout << "Y" << endl;// ERROR CHECK 3 : VALID NUMBER RANGE
    file.close();
}
```